# PL/SQL: setting a column value by its name in a trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, plsql, httprequest, httpresponse

I've created a trigger on my Oracle base.

```
TRIGGER Customer_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON Customer
FOR EACH ROW
```

It connects by a http request to some service. The service gives columns and theirs values in the response. My problem is how to set column value by its name. I'd like to do something like this.

```
column_name := from http response
column_value := from http response
:new.<column_name> := column_value
```

I've tried to use execute immediate with no luck.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't change the value of the columns in an AFTER INSERT trigger - you can use the `:NEW.<column_name> := ` syntax in a BEFORE INSERT trigger, however.

Comment: My mistake! It's BEFORE trigger.

Comment: When you say "I've tried to use execute immediate with no luck" what happened - or didn't happen?  Please show us your code and other relevant details, including error messages.

Comment: Sorry I don't provide enough info, but I've tried so many ways... Generally I had troubles binding the "new" variable to anonymous block.

Comment: Perhaps you could try something like this: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || nColumn_value || ' INTO :NEW.' || strColumn_name || ' FROM DUAL'`.  Honestly, though, I think that performing an HTTP request from a trigger is just BEGGING for problems.  Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*.  I think it's reasonable to say that the HTTP request should be done before executing the INSERT.  YMMV.

Comment: @BobJarvis - that would try to interpret the `:NEW` as a bind variable, which doesn't work. You need the `into` after the quoted SQL, and then you can't make what you're selecting into dynamic.

Comment: @AlexPoole - ahh - didn't realize you couldn't bind to :NEW.<colname>.  <grumble>...stupid language limitations...</grumble>.  Thanks.

Comment: i think you need to look at your data model and what you are trying to achieve again. There must be a better way of implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

you can't dynamically set column name in the trigger but you can do following:

```
case http_response.column_name
  when 'c1' then :new.c1 := http_response.column_value;
  when 'c2' then :new.c2 := http_response.column_value;
  when 'c3' then :new.c3 := http_response.column_value;
  ...
end case;
```

Comment: I upvoted this because it is a feasible solution.  However I do agree with @BobJarvis that the proposed scenario is a really bad implementation.